# running bash file works , using source doesn't

Tags: bash, shell

So i am trying to create a function to run through the terminal.

I created the following bash file : myfile.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

fun(){
   echo "this is a function"
}
fun
```

Running the file with `bash myfile.sh` works perfectly.

If i try to use `source myfile.sh` so I can run the function from the terminal, it complains about the parenthesis : Badly placed ()'s.

Am I forgetting anything? I found many guides online and copied and pasted the code and still couldn't source the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this problem when I executed the `source myfile.sh` after starting `csh` instead of `bash`. You can check your current shell using the command `echo $SHELL`.

If you want bash scripts to work when sourced, you will need to `chsh` your shell to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: `$SHELL` does *not* contain the name of the current shell; it contains the name of the current user's login shell.

Comment: My current $SHELL is /bin/tcsh might changing that to /bin/bash break anything already defined (maybe prevent me from running some already defined functions). I'm on my work computer so I'll ask around to see if there's any reason the default shell is tcsh

Comment: @Anthony: Why don't you try changing just the shebang to your login shell in the script `#!/bin/tcsh`?

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, changing the login shell did not work neither through chsh, nor through ypchsh. I will either change my script to use tcsh to be safe as pointed out by @l'L'l, or run bash manually (bash&). Is running bash manually safe? 
This answer did point out the problem so I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: Just a note, your script is bash only as written.